# shell script - is it okay as a .bat file? or cygwin more suited?

Tags: shell, batch-file

I found the following code on google for shell script. If I get rid of the bin/bash part, can I use it on Windows as .bat file? Or should I install cygwin?

```
#!/bin/bash


VIDEOS_DIR=/PATH/TO/JOOMLA/hwdvideos/uploads
YAMDI=/usr/local/bin/yamdi

for i in $VIDEOS_DIR/*.flv
do
    $YAMDI -w -i $i -o ${i}.tmp
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, as other commenters have said.

But, just for fun, here's the NT Command Script equivalent.

```
@echo off
set VIDEOS_DIR=c:\path\to\joomla\hwdvideos\upload
set YAMDI=c:\usr\local\bin\yamdi.exe

for /r %VIDEOS_DIR% %%i in (*.flv) do (
    %YAMDI% -w -i %%i -o %%i.tmp
)
```

Significantly different syntax, as you can see.

Comment: can you please tell me what exactly the line inside the loop is doing? It's breaking on me.

Comment: Basically, the line inside the loop is translating to ("C:\yamdi.exe" -w -i i.tmp ) which is wrong I guess.

Comment: The first reference to the `i` variable was wrong, missing a `%`. This is fixed. It should be placing the matched FLV file in place of `%%i` each time. Whether this is correct or not I cannot say, but it's what the original `sh` script was doing. I will note, also, that this will not work if pasted directly into a `cmd` prompt (it must be stored in a file and called).

Answer (score 3):

No. That is using specific Bash syntax that isn't supported by windows batch files. Your best bet is to using cygwin or convert this to the appropriate batch file syntax.

Answer (score 2):

No; batch files use different syntax.

You can convert it to Windows command-line syntax or run it in bash.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need Cygwin. This is strictly bash script content. You could rewrite it to work as  a batch file, but `yamdi` wouldn't work from it. (I don't know what `yamdi` is, but it's most likely a Linux application.)